# Can a batsman be run out after the ball is dead?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, wicket

Can a batsman be run out after an umpire signals over?

My friend was batting outside the crease, and the ball went to a fielder. He was not taking a run.

The umpire called "Over", and my friend went to talk to the non-striker at his end. Then the bails came off.

Is this Out, or Dead Ball, or something else?

Answer (score 6):

The *meaning* of the dead ball is **no further actions can be performed after the ball is declared as dead**. That means neither batsmen can run nor fielders can run-out them.

See [Dead ball - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_ball#Cricket)

> In cricket, a dead ball is a particular state of play in which **the players may not perform any of the active aspects of the game**. In other words, **batsmen may not score runs and fielders may not attempt to get batsmen out**.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can get run out after the umpire signals over. When the umpire signals over, the six deliveries are all finished, and there is no further play.

Answer (score 3):

[Law 22.4](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-22-the-over/) call of over states that

> When 6 valid balls have been bowled and when the ball becomes dead, the umpire shall call Over before leaving the wicket.

and [Law 23.3](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-23-dead-ball/) states

> Neither the call of Over, nor the call of Time is to be made until the ball is dead.

As umpire already signaled over that means ball is dead and he can't be run out.